# How can I use a GET from my php file, to get a variable that I declared in my .js file?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, get

I made some variables that contain the answers that are selected in my dropdown menu's. Now I want to use those variables in my .php file so i can make a query of them. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, so here is my code.

This my main.js file:

```
$("#slctTable").change(function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("slctTable");
    var tableSelected = table.value;

    console.log(tableSelected);
});

$("#slctField").change(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("slctField");
    var fieldSelected = field.value;

    console.log(fieldSelected);
});

$("#slctAttribute").change(function(){
    var attribute = document.getElementById("slctAttribute");
    var attributeSelected = attribute.value;

    console.log(attributeSelected);
});
```

And this my getData.php file:

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$test1 = $_GET['tableSelected'];
$test2 = $_GET['fieldSelected'];
$test3 = $_GET['attributeSelected'];

echo ($test1);
echo ($test2);
echo ($test3);

?>
```

Comment: To transmit a value to a PHP script, you need to actually call the PHP script.
Once the user has made his selection in your dropdown menus, what is supposed to happen ?

Comment: JavaScript is a client side language and PHP is a server side language. You can't get values out of JavaScript in PHP. The only way for PHP to access them is for you to include them in the URL.

Comment: I wanna use AJAX to do this. And the information the user selects will be thrown in a pg/sql query that will be displayed in a leaflet map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to redirect the user to a page with the variables in the URL. PHP runs a script on the server then sends the output of that script to the client. JavaScript only runs on the client. You can do this:

```
$('#slctTable').change(function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("slctTable");
    var tableSelected = table.value;

    console.log(tableSelected);
    window.location.href = "?tableSelected=" + tableSelected
});
```

Alternatively you can make an Ajax request to make a call to the server without refreshing the page. You can use this:

```
$('#slctTable, #slctField, #slctAttribute').change(function ()
{
    var tableSelected = document.getElementById("slctTable").value;
    var fieldSelected = document.getElementById("slctField").value;
    var attributeSelected = document.getElementById("slctAttribute").value;
    $.ajax({
        "url": "getData.php",
        "type": "GET",
        "data": {
            tableSelected: tableSelected,
            fieldSelected: fieldSelected,
            attributeSelected: attributeSelected
        }
    })
    .done(function (response)
    {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked Styphon. But now I have another problem. When I only do a GET to tableSelected it works. But when I add the code for the fieldSelected and attributeSelected i get an Unidentified index error. And it does pass the right values but I also get the error in my debugger. (I used you'r Ajax solution btw)

Comment: So you need to pass through all three always?

Comment: Yeah i need to pass them all through. If the user selects nothing in a dropdown menu it needs to turn up empty. But most of the time the user will select value's in the three dropdowns.

Comment: I've updated my answer to grab all three values and pass them to getData any time one of the fields is changed.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But if i remove the .done(function(response) part of your code i get: `Connection Keep-Alive` in the header. Is that forming a security risk? Or is it just away to retrieve mutiple variables faster?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060959/http-is-statel-less-so-what-does-it-mean-by-keep-alive explains keep alive. It's not a security risk.

Comment: Oww oké, so that's why you implemented the `.done(function (response)`? To close the connection?

Comment: No, I implemented that because surely you'll want to do something with the response, even if it's just to check it completed properly.

Comment: And what if i also want all the records in the dropdown to be visible and not only the selected value? So for exmaple i want to have a variable that has the array of the dropdown tables in it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery, you could use Ajax to accomplish that:

```
$("#slctTable").change(function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("slctTable");
    var tableSelected = table.value;

    console.log(tableSelected);
});

$("#slctField").change(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("slctField");
    var fieldSelected = field.value;

    console.log(fieldSelected);
});
$("#slctAttribute").change(function(){
    var tableSelected = slctTable.val();
    var fieldSelected= slctField.val();
    var attributeSelected = $(this).val();

     $.get( "getData.php?tableSelected="+tableSelected+"&fieldSelected="+fieldSelected+"&attributeSelected="+attributeSelected )
                    .fail(function(data){

                        alert('Ajax Call Error');
                    })
                    .done(function(){
                        alert('Success');
                        });
                    });
});
```